# Можно ли в Yii2 advanced вытащить все папки из Frontend в корневую?

Tags: yii2

Мне не нужно разделение на фронтенд и бэкенд. Возможно ли вытащить все из папки фронтенд в корневую и удалить папку бэкенд. Что бы папка web тоже была в корне. Нужно ли менять конфигурационные файлы или ещё что нибудь?

Answer (score 0):

Если не нужно разделение, то вместо шаблона advanced, используйте шаблон basic